# Is the CFDUMP tag modifiable?

Tags: coldfusion

With ColdFusion MX7 if we encounter an exception we send an email to the development team containing dumps of the various data scopes including the form structure.

This works great for debugging except in the case of an error when the user logs in.  We end up getting the password printed out.

So, the question is, is there a way to modify the CFDUMP file so that it filters the password value out of the form object?

Naturally we could put it in the same code that sends the email, however it would be ideal to put it in the CFDUMP file so that we do not have to worry about it showing up in other spots.

I have located the CFDUMP file and it seems to be binary, so I'm guessing we can't do it.

Comment: Wouldn't really address your problem, even if you were on CF8, but worth noting: <cfdump var="#form#" hide="password"> :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy the dump.cfm file to dumporiginal.cfm, and then make a new dump.cfm that calls dumporiginal.cfm.

```
<!--- 
  So that it won't execute twice if you 
  have a closing slash (<cfdump ... />) 
---> 
<cfif thisTag.executionMode neq "start">
  <cfexit method="exitTag" />
</cfif>


<!--- 
  defaults for optional attributes, taken from the docs 
  http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_d-e_08.html
--->
<cfparam name="attributes.expand" default="yes" />
<cfparam name="attributes.format" default="html" />     
<cfparam name="attributes.hide" default="all" />     
<cfparam name="attributes.keys" default="9999" />     
<cfparam name="attributes.label" default="" />      
<cfparam name="attributes.metainfo" default="yes" />     
<cfparam name="attributes.output" default="browser" />     
<cfparam name="attributes.show" default="all" />     
<cfparam name="attributes.showUDFs" default="yes" />     
<cfparam name="attributes.top" default="9999" />     

<!--- Hide the password, but store its value to put it back at the end --->
<cfif isStruct(attributes.var) and structKeyExists(attributes.var, 'password')>
  <cfset originalPassword = attributes.var.password />
  <cfset attributes.var.password = "{hidden by customized cfdump}"/>
</cfif>   

<!--- 
   Call the original cfdump. 
   Which attributes you pass depends on CF version. 
--->              
<cfswitch expression="#listFirst(server.coldfusion.productVersion)#">
<cfcase value="6">
  <cfdumporiginal 
      var = "#attributes.var#"
      expand = "#attributes.expand#" 
      hide = "#attributes.hide#"
      label = "#attributes.label#"
      >
</cfcase>
<cfcase value="7">
  <cfdumporiginal 
      var = "#attributes.var#"
      expand = "#attributes.expand#" 
      hide = "#attributes.hide#"
      label = "#attributes.label#"
      top = "#attributes.top#"
      >
</cfcase>  
<cfdefaultcase>     
  <cfdumporiginal 
      var = "#attributes.var#"
      expand = "#attributes.expand#" 
      format = "#attributes.format#"
      hide = "#attributes.hide#"
      keys = "#attributes.keys#"
      label = "#attributes.label#"
      metainfo = "#attributes.metainfo#"
      output = "#attributes.output#"
      show = "#attributes.show#"
      showUDFs = "#attributes.showUDFs#"
      top = "#attributes.top#"
      >
</cfdefaultcase>
</cfswitch>

<!--- Restore the password, in case it's read after cfdump call ---> 
<cfif isDefined("originalPassword")>
  <cfset attributes.var.password = originalPassword />
</cfif>
```

Comment: I only tested in CF8, but in theory it should work in CF6/7/8+.

Comment: BTW, on my machine (CF8 developer edition on OS X) I found dump.cfm at  /Applications/ColdFusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cftags

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think there is a way to modify `<cfdump>`'s behavior. I can't be sure, obviously. It's *thinkable* that such a hack exists, though it's not necessarily *recommendable*.

Why not go with a simple:

```
<cftry>
  <cfset DoSomethingThatFails()>

  <cfcatch>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(FORM, "Password")>
      <cfset FORM.Password = "***">
    </cfif>
    <cfdump var="#FORM#">
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: That's my guess to.  The reason is basically so that it is replaced in instances that aren't expected.  If someone just sticks a dump in for a test or something.

Comment: Oh, and your example actually changes the value of password, which probably isn't a problem because it's in an error situation.  It's probably better to duplicate the struct first though.

Comment: Yeah, it was mainly to make my point clear. If you can't trust the people that maintain the system you are screwed anyway, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

CFDUMP began life as a custom tag (CF_DUMP) way back in the CF5 days. You could always get the code for that custom tag and modify it to your needs and use that instead of the built-in tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only the password that is a problem of showing? If so, perhaps the solution is to salt/hash the password? That I think is good practice anyway.

http://blog.mxunit.org/2009/06/look-ma-no-password-secure-hashing-in.html